# Remove trailing numbers from field with SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table for tags. Since some users have done copy-paste from our website the some tags occur with count numbers at the end, like so:

```
Tag1
Tag1 (5)
Tag2
Tag1 (7)
```

As far as i know, mysql doesn't support regex replace, so how can i remove these?

I don't want to do it with php cause the table is large, and i'd like to run it regulary.

Expected end result:

```
Tag1
Tag1
Tag2
Tag1
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can achive this by using [string functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html):

```
SELECT TRIM(SUBSTRING(tag, 1, (CHAR_LENGTH(tag) - LOCATE('(', REVERSE(tag))))) AS new_tag
FROM table_name;
```

**[SQLFIDDLE DEMO HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/76000/2)**

Comment: It fails at some point. See http://kristian.ee/share/sql-regex.png
I have no ide whats wrong.

Comment: It is failing when multibyte character(UTF-8) inside word:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/76000/1

Comment: ohh yes. we should be using `CHAR_LENGTH` function instead of `LENGTH`. try updated post.